# Passing dynamic array to ImageSlideshow ios

Tags: ios, json, swift

Iam trying to use **[ImageSlideshow](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow)
** library

and i followed the documentation step by step and it's working perfectly

but i  can  only pass static images and here's my code :

slideShow.setImageInputs([AFURLSource(urlString: "https://mylink.com/image.jpg")!, AFURLSource(urlString: "https://mylink.com/image2.jpg")!, AFURLSource(urlString: "https://mylink.com/image3.jpg")!])

But i need to get the images url from JSON array dynamically and pass it to slideshow like that :

```
var jsonArray:NSarray = [String] 

slideShow.setImageInputs([jsonArray])
```

any idea how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
let arr =  jsonArray.map { AFURLSource(urlString: $0 as! String)!}
slideShow.setImageInputs(arr)
```

hope it be helpful :-)

Comment: i got this error 

 Cannot convert value of type '[AFURLSource?]' to expected argument type '[InputSource]'